# Display Incremented Row number against every row in Mysql View

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying increment a number against every row in Mysql View.
First i tried this Mysql code

```
set @row_number=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number + 1 AS num,name,last_name from `users` limit 5
```

And it gives me this result

[image]

Result is Perfect,but now i want this same query in Mysql View,but in Mysql View i am facing issue.Let me share a query with you guys

```
set @row_number=0;
CREATE VIEW user_view 
            as SELECT
            @row_number:=@row_number + 1 AS num,
            name,
            last_name
            from
            `users`
```

but it throws this error

[image]

Can someone guide me what is the issue behind?Do we user Variables in Mysql View?.I search alot on this thing but nothing find any thing
Please Suggest any solution.Thanks

Comment: No you cannot use variables in a view, what version of mysql are you on

Comment: @P.Salmon I am using Mysql v 10.1

Comment: Mysql latest version is in the 8. range to get the version -  show variables where variable_name ='version';

Comment: The restriction on views include 'The SELECT statement cannot refer to system variables or user-defined variables.' see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html

Comment: @P.Salmon yes that is my mistake.I had told you the Maria-Db version before.Mysql version is 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a query, remember to add PDO or prepared statements.
looping the the info and creating a table with the number loop number.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbname";




$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    echo "</style>
    
    <table class='m2' border='1' width='80%'>
    <tr>
    <th>num</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>last_name</th>
    </tr>";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      
    echo ($i % 2)?'<tr class="bg-white">':'<tr class="bg-secondary1">'; // alternating colours
    
    echo "<td>" . ($i+1) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
    
    
    
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
    }
    
    }
    echo "</table> <br>";
```